# Dell PowerEdge R820 with a PERC H710 Raid Controller

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc, drac, dell-openmanage

I just did a planned disks replacement on our Dell PowerEdge R820 with a PERC H710 Raid Controller. Which I have done quite a few times before without any issues, but tonight I am running into a very strange scenario.

When the replacement completed the replaced drive is still showing as part of the Virtual Disk Configuration but with a Mirror Set ID: Not Applicable. See below.

[image: Dell OpenManage Server Admininstrator - Virtual Disk Configuration]

All 5 discs show as online when I view the Physical Disks in OpenManage.

[image: Dell OpenManage Server Administrator - Physical Disks]

However when I connect via iDrac only 4 of the drives show as online when I look at the Physical Disks

[image: Dell iDrac - Physical Disks]

When viewing the Virtual Disk via iDrac 4 disks show are part of the array, but the one being the disk that has just been replaced and is in Ready State.

[image: Dell iDrac - Virtual Disk Configuration]

How do I resolve this? 
Do I restart the server?
Do I take the drive offline?
Just worried I am going to damage the Virtual Disk.

Please advise. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as the forms are currently read-only.

Answer (score 1):

This may just be a side-effect of using non-validated drives with the PERC controller, or potentially from using an outdated version of OMSA. It's almost certainly just a software error though, given that the iDRAC shows what you'd expect.

Try restarting the windows services for OpenManage Server Administrator - there should be 4, each starting with "DSM SA ..." to force the management software to reassess its view of the storage. A reboot would do the trick too though, and that would give you the option to enter the PERC BIOS (Ctrl + R) to verify the health state from there, and even start a virtual disk repair from outside the OS (which would continue progressing once booting back into Windows).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Stopping and starting the services did not help, but I did update the OMSA to the latest version after which everything reported correctly.